# Dagger2 conversion to android.dagger

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I studied some tutorials about new dagger.android approach but can't make it right. I built a simple tutorial with subcomponent builder but i can't convert this to new approach. All tutorials and articles leave required parts empty.

This example is for learning purposes may not be suitable for practical situations and i only intended implementing field injection, constructor injection may be more appropriate.

Scope

```
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ActivityScope {
}
```

Parent Component

```
@Component(modules = ApplicationModule.class)
@Singleton
public interface ApplicationComponent {

    // Calls SubComponent Builder from MainActivity using ApplicationComponent
    ToastMakerSubComponent.Builder toastMakerBuilder();
}
```

Parent Module, i didn't use @BindsInstance in app module for learning different approaches

```
@Module(subcomponents = {ToastMakerSubComponent.class})
public class ApplicationModule {

    private Context context;

    public ApplicationModule(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    SharedPreferences provideSharedPreferences() {
        System.out.println("ApplicationModule context: " + context);
        return context.getSharedPreferences("PrefName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
}
```

Sub Component

```
@ActivityScope
@Subcomponent(modules = {ToastMakerModule.class})
public interface ToastMakerSubComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);

    /*
     Builder is called from Parent Component,
      and parent component is called from scope(Activity, Fragment, etc.)
      */
    @Subcomponent.Builder
    interface Builder {

        ToastMakerSubComponent build();

        @BindsInstance
        Builder context(Context context);
    }
}
```

Sub Component Module

```
@Module
public class ToastMakerModule {

    @ActivityScope
    @Provides
    ToastMaker provideToastMaker(Context context) {
        System.out.println("ToastMakerModule context: " + context);
        return new ToastMaker(context);
    }
}
```

Instantiate ApplicationComponent inside MyApplication

```
 mApplicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent
                .builder()
                .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(getApplicationContext()))
                .build();
```

And get sub component inside Activity

```
ApplicationComponent applicationComponent = ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getApplicationComponent();

ToastMakerSubComponent toastMakerSubComponent = applicationComponent
        .toastMakerBuilder()
        .context(this)
        .build();

toastMakerSubComponent.inject(this);
```

---

After following [this](https://google.github.io/dagger//android.html), [this](http://www.riptutorial.com/dagger-2/example/30350/android-example), and [this](https://proandroiddev.com/dagger-2-annotations-binds-contributesandroidinjector-a09e6a57758f) tutorial i built the following as

```
@Component(modules = ApplicationModule.class)
@Singleton
public interface ApplicationComponent {
// What should i put here ???

}
```

Parent module but i didn't get how i should provide `provideSharedPreferences`

```
@Module(subcomponents = {ToastMakerSubComponent.class})
abstract class ApplicationModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ActivityKey(MainActivity.class)
    abstract AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends MainActivity>
    bindYourActivityInjectorFactory(ToastMakerSubComponent.Builder builder);

}
```

Sub component is missing `ToastMakerSubComponent build();` and  `@BindsInstance Builder context(Context context);` how should i add these to this component.

```
@ActivityScope
@Subcomponent(modules = {ToastMakerModule.class})
public interface ToastMakerSubComponent extends AndroidInjector<MainActivity> {
    // ??? Is this required?
    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);

    @Subcomponent.Builder
     abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<MainActivity> {
         ???
    }
}
```

Also i see `@ContributesAndroidInjector`, where does it fit in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the diff of changes: https://www.diffchecker.com/3IL8UQ7P

Make app component extend `AndroidInjector<MyApplication>` and include the `AndroidSupportInjectionModule`

```
@Component(modules = {ApplicationModule.class, AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class})
@Singleton
public interface ApplicationComponent extends AndroidInjector<MyApplication> {

}
```

Make the subcomponent extend `AndroidInjector<MainActivity>` and the builder `AndroidInjector.Builder<MainActivity>`, use `seedInstance` to provide arguments to `@BindsInstance` methods.

```
@ActivityScope
@Subcomponent(modules = {ToastMakerModule.class})
public interface ToastMakerSubComponent extends AndroidInjector<MainActivity> {

    @Subcomponent.Builder
    abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<MainActivity> {

        @Override
        public void seedInstance(MainActivity instance) {
            context(instance);
        }

        @BindsInstance
        public abstract Builder context(Context context);
    }
}
```

Add a binding for the subcomponent builder to a module installed in the app component:

```
@Module(subcomponents = {ToastMakerSubComponent.class})
public abstract class ApplicationModule {

    private Context context;

    public ApplicationModule(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    SharedPreferences provideSharedPreferences() {
        System.out.println("ApplicationModule context: " + context);
        return context.getSharedPreferences("PrefName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ActivityKey(MainActivity.class)
    abstract AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends Activity> bindMainActivityFactory(ToastMakerSubComponent.Builder builder);
}
```

Let framework classes extend the `Dagger*` counterparts, or implement `Has*Injector` interfaces if you can't use inheritance

```
public class MyApplication extends DaggerApplication {

    @Override
    protected AndroidInjector<? extends DaggerApplication> applicationInjector() {
        return DaggerApplicationComponent.create();
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends DaggerAppCompatActivity {

    @Inject
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Inject
    ToastMaker toastMaker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toastMaker.showToast("sharedPreferences " + sharedPreferences);
    }
}
```